# Redirect 301 for Active Forum

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-code-301

thanks for reading, pls help out if u can :)

if i want to redirect the entire forum.jalan2.com to subfolder, whats the best way to do it ?

So its on jalan2.com/forum/

How to make EVERY PAGE redirect correctly when accessed from the google ?

Say this page :

forum.jalan2.com/topic/9689-mimiland-batu-payung-village-singkawang-bengkayang/

So it becomes

jalan2.com/forum/topic/9689-mimiland-batu-payung-village-singkawang-bengkayang/

---

I dont want thousands of the old pages to redirect to only 1 page which is forum  home at jalan2.com/forum/

i want each page redirect exactly to the new page location

---

Thanks :)

Rudy

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess in your web root / directory of forum.jalan2.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.jalan2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jalan2.com/forum/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]